# StreamProvider returns null even though the data is fetched from FireStore

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, stream, provider

I am trying to stream data fetched from firestore. It does not work because StreamProvider does not seem to listen to the fetched data even though the data is fetched and can be logged on the process.

```
Performing hot reload...
Syncing files to device AOSP on IA Emulator...
Reloaded 3 of 605 libraries in 407ms.
I/flutter (22698): CvKGDloy8gsuLYIdjO9w
I/flutter (22698): [822, 930, 1030, 1145, 1250, 1355, 1555, 1640, 1800, 1900, 2000, 2100, 2130, 2200]
```

The code below initiates StreamProvider.

```
//app.dart
if (snapshot.hasData) {
    final _streamBusSchedules = ApiService().streamBusSchedules();
    return StreamProvider<List<BusSchedule>>.value(
        initialData: [BusSchedule.initialData()],
        value: _streamBusSchedules,
        catchError: (_, __) => null,
        child: HomePage(title: 'My Amazing App'),
    );
}
```

The code below only returns 'Loading...' text since _busSchedules is null.

```
//home_page.dart
Widget _buildList(BuildContext context) {
    var _busSchedules = Provider.of<List<BusSchedule>>(context);
    if (_busSchedules != null) {
      return ListView.builder(
        itemExtent: 40.0,
        itemCount: _busSchedules.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) =>
            _buildListItem(context, _busSchedules[index]),
      );
    }
    
    return Center(
      child: Text('Loading...'),
    );
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text(title),
        ),
        body: _buildList(context),
    );
}
```

The code below handles fetching the data from firestore.

```
//api.dart  
class ApiService {
    final FirebaseFirestore _db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
    Stream<List<BusSchedule>> streamBusSchedules() async* {
      var ref = _db.collection('bus-schedules');
      await for (final snapshot in ref.snapshots()) {
        yield snapshot.docs.map((doc) => BusSchedule.fromMap(doc)).toList();
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was because BusSchedule.fromMap(doc) was only returned once for not meeting type requirements.

```
class BusSchedule {
  final String id;
  final String name;
  final List<int> weekdays;
```

Apparently, `List<int>` is not happy with the array of numbers. Changed it to just `List` and the stream provider returned the list of BusSchedule just fine.